# Do I need a "of the" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage, grammar

> Everything about his face, was circular, like most (of the) ingredients of a hamburger.

Do I need *of the*. Why or why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well no, you are talking about most ingredients or most of the ingredients. It doesn't matter. I would put:

> Everything about his face was circular, like most *of the* ingredients in a hamburger.

Note I have put `in a` instead of `of a` and removed the comma in `face, was` to make the flow run smoother

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need "of the."

Without, you are discussing most of an unknown/non-specific set of ingredients in hamburgers generally.

With, you are discussing most of the specific ingredients in a hamburger.

If I recall correctly, we call these "unspecific" and "specific" groups.